# Good Javascript plugin to display tooltip briefly on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, tooltip

I need a plugin which highlights/points to a div box on the page on page load. The tooltip should then be able to be closed and/or will disappear after a few seconds.
I am having difficulty finding one, as all the current ones seem to require the mouse to hover over the intended target.

Are there any plugins that people recommend out of experience? I use Jquery, so ideally it would be in Javascript and/or JQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) is the best tooltip I've ever seen. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [jgrowl](http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html) is what you need.

If you are looking for "loading" message like on gmail then there is [this plugin](http://jquery-values.googlecode.com/svn/other/loading/jquery.loading.htm)